# regex to extract html value

Tags: html, regex

im trying to write small scraper script from google search, im write the program, bat have small problem i need regex for extract data-href value from google search, please help me :

exemple html code of google search :

```
data-href="www.buxmob.net/index.php?id=577">
data-href="www.webopedia.com/TERM/K/keyword.html">
data-href="moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo/keyword-research">
```

need only the url present in this value, only this :

```
hxxp://www.webopedia.com/TERM/K/keyword.html
hxxp://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo/keyword-research
hxxp://www.buxmob.net/index.php?id=577
```

thanks you

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regexes. Use a proper parser (which make xpath's very yummy).

Comment: Scraping Google search results is against their TOS. You need to sign up for an API key and go about this the legitimate way.

Comment: im use ubotstudio, is not possible use external script !

Comment: # Marc B google api gives me a few results

Comment: Obligatory reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: im use this in ubotstudio, uniq street is regex ! need regex !

Comment: Just because you know regex does not mean every problem can be solved using regexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the examples you gave can be matched with

```
(?:data-href=")(.*?)(?:">)
```

See demo at http://regex101.com/r/rB4nS1

That does NOT mean it's a good idea to try to parse (general) html with regex - but sometimes, when the response is well formed and well known, you get away with it.

Note that you mentioned you wanted `hxxp://` in front of the string - that is not the job of the regular expression, but belongs with the language you use to implement the expression. The above is a "non greedy match starting after the string `data-href="` and ending at the next `">`